# Did I fall for an Amazon scam? (Amazon Photos Credit)

Tags: spam, amazon

So just 30 minutes ago, I was looking through some emails that ended up in my scam, and as usual there are amazon emails with recommendations based on past purchases and stuff like that. Then there is these new email asking that if I were to upload a photo to Amazon Photos I may be eligible for $10 in amazon credit. So in a moment of weakness I uploaded a photo and so on. Then I realized that this may have been a scam. I look through the email and I only find the link Amazon.com. This potentially scam email came from store-news@amazon.com. According to amazon, links ending with "@amazon.com" are real, however some people on Facebook claim it to be a scam. After uploading a photo I get an email that did not end up In my spam folder from no-reply@amazon.com. I got on a live chat and the first person I spoke to said that it was a scam, and that amazon does not offer such credit. He put me on with someone in the appropriate department and she said that it was not a scam. Can anyone confirm if this is indeed a scam. I have setup two-factor authentication and changed my password and got rid of unnecessary information on my account, but I am kinda freaking out. Any clear information would be great.

Comment: Googling "amazon photos 10 dollars", the first result is a page on Amazon.com that talks about that offer (https://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=16334255011). If you logged in to the real Amazon website and uploaded your pics there, you have nothing to worry about. But you need to make sure you actually only interacted with the real Amazon website. Check all the links in the email, and your browsing history too, if you aren't sure what pages you actually visited.

Answer (score 1):

If you kept to the terms and conditions and received the credit it clearly wasn't a scam.

There is such a offer from Amazon for people who haven't used Amazon Photo before.

So otherwise than the other answers point out this might be NOT a scam.

But that doesn't mean you should be reckless - always check the links before clicking on them.

Answer (score -1):

Some Scammers are actually addressing the actual 'senders address' as CC, so you email program actually displays the CC instead of the senders-address.

So you maybe need to click on the Addresses-Bar to see the sender (or post a photo of the sender?) - scamemrs got a little more tricky these days.

It's actually more important on which address you **entered your personal data**.
But if you enabled two-factor and changed **every** account associated with this password 

*(maybe you used the same password for your email account?!)* - then you should be save by now.

Comment: I've contacted two reps and they say I have nothing to worry about. Just incase, I changed the password and enabled two-factor auth. The link to Amazon photos where I went t upload a single image was real.

Answer (score -1):

Total S C A M

This one is well put together. The address Looks real. But it is a scam. Many people fall for these scams. Good job in pulling back in time.